# Math font matching Rosetta Skolar

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am searching for a (almost complete) Math font (free or commercial), which fits well to the Rosetta Skolar Serif (https://www.rosettatype.com/Skolar). Can anyone recommend a font?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try charter.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418217/5001) to the query [Which LuaLaTeX math fonts have complete symbol set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418211/5001)? If you add the instruction `\setmainfont{Rosetta Skolar}` (or whatever is most appropriate) immediately after `\usepackage{unicode-math} and rerun the example code, you should be at a good starting point for evaluating which math font might be most suitable.

Comment: Thx! But I don't have any typographical experience; therefore, I am not sure whether a font couple is really suitable or not. Just trying different combinations don't tell me if it is a proper pairing. Do you know what I mean?