# different math fonts in xelatex using unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, xetex

I have expect two different types of `math fonts` required in `$ ... $`. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmathfont{Calibri}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title here}

From the Egyptian pyramids to modern architecture, points, lines and   angles
are everywhere. $a^\circ$ Geometry is a $\alpha + \beta$ very visual    element of mathematics where the
designs of buildings and the orbits of planets can be studied using basic
objects like points, lines and circles.

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{10cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Variabili} & $\mathbf{Descrizione}$ \\
\midrule
$\alpha + \beta$ & $a+b$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Thales (624--546~BCE) is known to be the founder of Greek geometry. He was an astronomer and $a^\circ$ philosopher, and $\alpha + \beta$ eclipse.
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear it would be better to put the words in text rather than have the question in small font in an image. But why do you expect any text to be in Helvetica?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I would like to differ the `$` math font in different fonts. Text `$...$` is different font and Table `$...$` is different font.

Comment: To use two different math font families, load the `unicode-math` package and use math-versions, as explained in the user guide of the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a now a `Calibri Math` OpenType math font?

Comment: For an example of a document with 12 [!] different math font families, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418217/5001) to the query [Which LuaLaTeX math fonts have complete symbol set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418211/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert!) That question is ostensibly about LuaLaTeX, but it applies to XeLaTeX as well.

Comment: @Mico: How to set two different math-version in `unicode-math`.

Comment: unlike mathspec the unicode-math package requires an opentype math font and calibri is only availabe as a text font (unlike cambria which has the Cambria Math font) why can you not just ise `\mathsf{abc}` to get sans serif text in your math where needed?

Comment: @Balaji - Please indicate *which* math fonts you wish to employ.

Comment: @Mico the original (now deleted) image suggested Calibri and Helvetica (neither or which is a math font....)

Comment: @Mico: I would like to get `sans-serif font like helveticaneue lt` font in `table`. It's possible?

Comment: @Balaji - `Helvetica Neue` is a (rather well-known!) text font. The problem is that there is no *math* font that's based on Helvetica Neue.

Comment: It's possible to create `Helvetica Neue Math` font? Pl. advise