# Aesthetic Integral Symbols

Tags: typography

I don't like the look of the standard integral typesetting. Does anyone know where to find an integral symbol like the one in the following image?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign

Comment: There is no such thing as „standard integral typesetting“ —  it‘s determined entirely by the math font that’s been loaded. It looks like you’re looking for a Times Roman clone — which one? (There are quite a few Tins Roman clone math fonts out there: not all of their integral symbols look alike.)

Comment: Thanks @Mico ! Where would I find a list of those fonts and the integral signs they produce?

Comment: @CaelanRavel - Please check out [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001), [Which LuaLaTeX math fonts have complete symbol set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418211/5001), and [how to select math font in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30049/5001). Since you appear to be interested in Times Roman-type fonts, just focus on the parts of the answers that touch on Times Roman clones.