# Which math fonts offer ∀ and ∃ quantifiers with thick strokes and stems?

Tags: fonts, symbols, typography

I'm looking for a math font that has thick strokes and stems like in serif characters (but actually without the serifs) for the `\forall` (∀) and `\exists` (∃) quantifiers (I can use OpenType fonts as well).

I noticed that Asana Math has such quantifiers:

[image]

But not  STIX Two Math for example:

[image]

Please forgive me if I didn't name the typographic properties correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not many, it seems...

I borrowed Mico's file from here

[Which LuaLaTeX math fonts have complete symbol set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418211/which-lualatex-math-fonts-have-complete-symbol-set/418217#418217)

and changed the text to include forall and exists, I didn't have one of the fonts so that is commented out but of the remaining ones, only asana, it seems:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\blurb{%
   $\forall \land \exists$}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%% Load 10 math fonts, plus two alternate/stylistic set variants
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=XITS]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[StylisticSet=1,version=XITS1]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2] % see http://stixfonts.org/
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=Asana]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Alternate,version=AsanaAlt]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=DejaVu]
%\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=Libertinus]

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Latin Modern & \mathversion{LM}      \blurb \\
Stix         & \mathversion{Stix}    \blurb \\
XITS         & \mathversion{XITS}    \blurb \\
XITS, StySet1& \mathversion{XITS1}   \blurb \\
Stix Two     & \mathversion{Stix2}   \blurb \\
Cambria      & \mathversion{Cambria} \blurb \\
Asana        & \mathversion{Asana}   \blurb \\
Asana Alt    & \mathversion{AsanaAlt}\blurb \\
Pagella      & \mathversion{Pagella} \blurb \\
Termes       & \mathversion{Termes}  \blurb \\
DejaVu       & \mathversion{DejaVu}  \blurb \\[0.5ex]
%Neo Euler    & \mathversion{Euler}   \blurb \\[0.5ex]
Libertinus Math& \mathversion{Libertinus} \blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The “Asana Alt” was based on a code snippet I posted, and only affects the `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` alphabets. You might want to show Neo Euler. And it’s generally a good idea to look through the stylistic sets of XITS and [STIX Two](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix2-otf/StixTwoMath.pdf).

Comment: @Davislor I commented out Neo Euler as I appeared not to have it and was in a rush so didn't want to install at the time. I could get it I suppose....

Comment: I wish to comment that FreeFont FreeSerif has such quantifiers as well, and other appropriate math characters for typesetting with XeTeX with its latest unreleased version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I ended up borrowing Asana's symbols by using `[range={\forall, \exists}]`.